# help setting up and editing a db table

Tags: module, database, magento-1, controllers, forms

i have a custom module (magento 1.9.2 were i want to save a frontend form in the controller I have

```
    $contact = Mage::getModel('logo/logo');
    $contact->setData('entity_id', $custid);
    $contact->setData('cust_img', '/media/users/pic_'.$custid.'/'.$fname);
    $contact->save();
```

when i manually create a DB row  for with an `entity_id` matching that `$custid` i can change it with the form (I see the change reflected in DB) , so i know everything is setup properly, but I cant get the controller to create a new row with that `$custid` if one does not yet exsist (the `entity_id` is the primary key and does not auto increment for my table it has no other columns besides these two)

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$table = new Varien_Db_Ddl_Table();
$table->setName($this->getTable('logo/logo'));
$table->addColumn(
    'entity_id',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    10,
    array(
        'primary' => true,
        'nullable'=> false,
    )
);
$table->addColumn(
    'cust_img',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    255,
    array(
        'input'     => 'file',
        'nullable'=> false,
    )
);
$table->setOption('type', 'InnoDB');
$table->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: Could you post your install script please ?

Comment: added install script

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise trying to do it this way. 
Firstly, keep to Magento standards and use the **entity_id** as a unique auto incrementing column.

Add **cust_id** as a seperate column.
In your module Mysql Model you can always use the cust_id column as the main id which will be the one it loads with `getModel()->load()`e.g

```
protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('module/model', 'cust_id');
}
```

Comment: i tried it that way too but it still wont create new rows for new entries?

Comment: do i need to reset the auto increment?

Comment: i am really stuck? why cant i save new rows?

Comment: i see my ptoblem is if  i am changing the `Model_Resource_Logo` to  `Model_Resource_Logo` that is what makes the new rows not save any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what that last statement even means.

Comment: Does it matter if you put preset in instead of variables? Or change the entity_id to something not Integer? Or remove the primary key...for now as you could always use something different like an autoincrement key instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the answer I needed to tell magento the prime key is not AutoIncrement

```
<?php
class Name_Module_Model_Resource_Logo
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('logo/logo', 'entity_id');
        $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    }
}
```